# How to stop Imagedatagenerator().flow_from_directory from changing the order of loaded files

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

I have test images in my folder in the following order - 
[image]

But when I load the image files using ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory() using the following code, the files are loaded in a different order as shown -

```
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(128,128), classes= 
                                                         ['test'], batch_size=1, shuffle=False, 
                                                         class_mode=None, seed=42)

i=0
for i in range (0, len(test_batches)):
    print(test_batches.filenames[i])
```

[image]

How can I maintain the order of image files in the code, since I need to create an output .csv file having file names and their predicted class-labels in the same order as that in the test folder?

Answer (score 0):

Add `shuffle=False` to the `flow_from_directory` call. Note that this *may* have an adverse effect if you use it when training, but it should not affect validation/testing.

Comment: I have added it in the flowfromdirectory() call as in the code above, still it seems to have changed the order of files..

Comment: @psj It will sort the files in alphanumeric order, which is the order most things should sort it in. A folder has no inherent ordering, so the non-standard order that you see in windows explorer will have no effect on any code that you write.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, I noticed that there is a permutation in the order when the number of predictions are smaller than the batch number. Therefore I just checked and rolled the prediction array. I believe this happens because when ImageDataGenerator is initialized it calls one batch (not exactly calling) but if you add tf.print to the getitem, it will be called batch number of times. Maybe when there are a lot of prediction items it remembers to reset, but using gen.reset() does not help, so I'm not sure.

In short this function solved the problem for me:

```
def fix_prediction_order(prediction):
    if len(prediction) <= BATCH_SIZE:
        return prediction

    return np.roll(prediction, BATCH_SIZE, axis = 0)
```